# android emulator x86 close immediately

Tags: java, android, android-emulator, emulation

hello i have problam with android emulator x86

when i run emulator x86 close immediately error message “qemu-system-i386.exe has stopped working”

full in cmd:
Failed to open /qemu.conf, err: 2HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode.emulator: ERROR: AdbHostServer.cpp:102: Unable to connect to adb daemon on port:5037vcpu run failed for vcpu  0

i try to reduce ram from 2048 to 512mb pick low res device use software opengl try cold and quick bots
no matter I do it show the same error and close immediately

i have no problem with armv7 emulator work fine

run windows 7 64bit ultimate last update

i search many solutions on stack but it won't work

any id how i can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Your Avd is trying to search for a qemu.conf file in the root drive of where your android sdk is. To suppress this Create a qemu.conf file in the root drive of your Android SDK.
Example: G:/qemu.conf (G is my android sdk drive)
this is not the cause of your android SDK stopped working. because i had this error too. its some kind of bug of avd in the new Android studio/avd version.

Try this and see if your emulator still stops.
go to terminal of your android studio and give this command
(FOR WINDWOS)

> CD PATH_TO_YOUR_SDK_EMULATOR_FOLDER
>
> emulator -avd NAME_OF_YOUR_VIRTUAL_DEVICE

example: emulator -avd Pixel_3_XL_API_29

you can get your avd names using:-

> emulator -list-avds

Comment: I already did this i try run emulator from cmd with root path and run from androidsudio it self both has same result if you see i send you cmd result in question

Comment: did you try to run the terminal/cmd as administrator ?

Comment: yes i run in admin mode with out it it wont work at all

Comment: your android-sdk-build-tools version?

Comment: 29 sdk version i dont thing its about android sdk

Comment: well if i run emulator from android studio then i get those same errors as yours but i can use the emulator smoothly and i am running x86. my build tools version is 30 and windows 10 64bit . try to update it and see if it works. check the release notes https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/emulator AVD is part of the Android SDK Tools.